# How to setup an SELinux policy to allow only a specific context permission to 'execheap'

Tags: permissions, security, selinux

I want to enable the dynamic core in DOSBox but this is incompatible with SELinux as unconfined_t by default is not allowed to execute from the heap.

The SELinux troubleshooter suggests:

```
You must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'selinuxuser_execheap' boolean.

setsebool -P selinuxuser_execheap 1
```

This is a global setting, I believe. I don't want to explicitly allow executing from the heap from any process as this undermines SELinux's security. It also suggests that I could allow execheap for unconfined_t; which is almost as bad.

How do I create a new policy for use with the DOSBox binary that has explicit permission to execute code on the heap?

This is a [known-issue](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=66690) with DOSBox but a solution has yet to be implemented in the mainline.

Brownie points for helpful comments on why this is a **bad idea** for security.